# How can we implement Session management for WebHttpBinding WCF REST Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have been developing a WCF REST service using webHttpBinding Session mode as required.But I am getting this error always "**Contract requires Session, but Binding 'WebHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it.**" Can any one tell what would be the reason for this ?

Comment: You can use Token for every request! Once user is loggedin/register, return him a token and use it for every request! As stuartd said! there is no mechanism for Session in REST.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02a1efd8-af65-4bf1-9097-01e08511ce03/restful-wcf-with-session-required-throws-exception):

> You cannot use WebHttpBinding for session based communication as it
> doesn't support the concept of sessions.  I talked at length about
> sessions here -
> http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,af6e6325-2e30-42e3-acb9-57e1363fa51e.aspx.
>
> WebHttpBinding doesn't support session for the same reason
> BasicHttpBinding doesn't. If you really must have sessions then you
> will have to use a binding that supports it. However, PerSession
> activation is only one way to maintain per client state. Can you not
> use another mechanism, say passing a session id to the service that
> you use to wire up your own concept of session?