# Enable Token to my already working REST Service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have created REST Service, it works fine. When I call a method I will send me Json response.

Now I want to enable Token. I write code to generate Token and run it. It gives me following Error:

### Contract requires Session, but Binding 'WebHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it.

Please let me know what are the changes required to fix this issue.

#### Web Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Service.Service" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service.IService" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

#### Service Class Interface

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
//[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "GET",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "GetStudent")]
    string GetStudent();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "AuthenticateUser")]
    string AuthenticateUser(string user, string pwd);
}
```

#### Service Implementation Class

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
//[ServiceBehavior]
public class Service : IService
{
    string UserToken = string.Empty;
    public bool IsValidateUser()
    {
        //Getting the user token from client request
        if (OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.FindHeader("TokenHeader", "TokenNameSpace") == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string userIdentityToken = Convert.ToString(OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<string>("TokenHeader", "TokenNameSpace"));

        //Authenticating user with token, if it is validated then returning employee data
        if (userIdentityToken == UserToken)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string GetStudent()
    {

       JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       return js.Serialize(Student.GetStudent());

    }

    public string AuthenticateUser(string user, string pwd)
    {
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(user)) && !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(pwd)))
        {
            UserToken = OperationContext.Current.SessionId;
        }
        return UserToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we implement Session management for WebHttpBinding WCF REST Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257565/how-can-we-implement-session-management-for-webhttpbinding-wcf-rest-service)

Comment: So according to this what binding changes I have to replace WebHttpBinding to work like REST

Comment: Is there any other way to Maintain Session on webHttpBinding REST service.

Comment: Well, as far as I know, REST is supposed to be stateless. Maintaining a session seems to be counterintuitive. Is it only for authentication? then maybe you could ask a question on how to do authentication on REST endpoints. It would be preferable to google it first though.

Comment: I found another solution. I have created my custom token and validate. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution which is I have created a custom(combination of some values) encrypted token. And it works fine. I have to use database approach to use it.