# WCF service with session and .net windows as client

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, winforms, wcf-wshttpbinding

I am looking for WCF sample code with session enabled. When service is hosted needs to be consumed in windows .net application keeping session alive. Along with windows application same service should be easily consume by jquery ajax. We are already using wshttpbinding and session is available for we application but not for windows .net application.

Comment: 1. Sample for WCF with sessions: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188749/WCF-Sessions-Brief-Introduction 2. Sample for WCF with JSON: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec 3. download and combine both examples

Comment: Gone through both example already. When combined only ajax works but not the session in windows application!

Comment: Which binding do you use ? BasicHttpBinding or WSHttpBinding ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we implement Session management for WebHttpBinding WCF REST Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257565/how-can-we-implement-session-management-for-webhttpbinding-wcf-rest-service)

Comment: wshttpbinding. The constrain is we cannot use tcp binding.

Comment: If you want to build a WCF-service, which is consumable by jquery ajax, then you need to use binding **WebHttpBinding**. But **WebHttpBinding** does not support sessions. But take a look at this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/322436/Maintain-HTTP-Session-State-in-WCF-REST-Services-w

Comment: I am really surprised that no body had build WCF and .net windows application along with WCF session!

Comment: Please note that for your new projects, people don"t   use anymore WCF. These days devs you use ASP.NET MVC with Web API V2, because then it automatically works with Jquery, AJAX and JSON. Web API V2 supports both XML and JSON as response content type. More here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api